# How do I set a custom icon to a JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, imageicon

I am trying to set the JFrame icon to a custom image I have prepared. I am, however, getting this error when I write this code;

```
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;



public class Game
{
    
    
    ImageIcon logo = new ImageIcon(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("BounceAroundIcon.png"));
    

    public static void main (String[] args) 
    
    {

        

        
        JFrame window = new JFrame();
        
        window.setContentPane(new GamePanel());
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.setResizable(false);
        window.pack();
        window.setVisible(true);
        
        
    }
    
}
```

This has worked with another project of mine, but here it will not work. I'm new to Java programming, so sorry if this is obviously wrong.

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: You are not doing anything with the `logo` variable. Shouldn't there be a `window.setItcon()` or something? You could pass the `logo` there.

Comment: (1-) *This has worked with another project of mine, but here it will not work.* - so then compare the working code with the code that is not working to determine the difference.

Answer (score 1):

The class `JFrame` has a method [`setIconImage(Image)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#setIconImage-java.awt.Image-).
Therefore you need to get an `Image` from your `ImageIcon`.
Fortunately the `ImageIcon` class has a method [`getImage()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/ImageIcon.html#getImage--) returning an Ìmage`object.

So, putting these two things together, you need to do:

```
window.setIconImageImage(logo.getImage());
```